# UICollectionView insertItem -> adjust animation time?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uicollectionview

So, I have a UICollectionView where I insert new items.

I used the most of the suggestions from the [Collection View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW13) - section "Making Insertion and Deletion Animations More Interesting"

Is there a way to adjust the animation time? (Maybe I just missed it in the docs, but couldn't find any info on this)

PS: If I could edit the curve that would be cool too. You know Ease-In-Out and so forth.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can change any animation speed with CALayer. So for UICollectionView this looks like the following:

```
[self.collectionView.viewForBaselineLayout.layer setSpeed:0.1f];
```

And you can change back the original speed:

```
[self.collectionView.viewForBaselineLayout.layer setSpeed:1.0f];
```

For this to work you may need to import QuartzCore:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked exactly in the way I wanted it to.
Wouldn't have known the "viewForBaselineLayout"'s layer is the one i need to edit.

Comment: But to be honest, this also adjusts a lot of the animations inside of UiCollectionViewItems. Like Animated UIImageViews. One then has to adjust the animation duration of those to keep the speed.

Comment: Yes it's a hackish way though, but easy. Maybe you can found a better view to set the speed. It was just a quick test and worked.

Comment: Interesting, but as you say, hackish.

Answer (score 6):

Or just do

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void) {
  [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]];
}];
```

The animation duration will affect the internal duration of the collection view insertion animation.

Comment: This is the way to go. You can also call this on `-performBatchUpdates` with any type of animation block you want and it will perform it on any updates in there!

Comment: As clever as the accepted answer is, this is the solution with the least potential for unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot adjust the animation with the Apple-provided layout methods. If you want to customize the animation you need to hide the item via attributes (just show and empty space), do your animation yourself and an at the end of the animation pop the item back in via attributes.

I asked a similar question about customizing the moving animation, but the consensus has been what I described. Animate yourself if you need to.

This question shows how to do a custom removal animation, customzing insertion should be similar: [UICollectionView horizontal scrolling, deleting last item, animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089144/uicollectionview-horizontal-scrolling-deleting-last-item-animation-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: It's true, and it sucks. The cell is a view like any other, though, so you can do whatever animations you like to it, as long as by the end the cell's position and size matches that of the layout attributes.

Comment: @jrturton so how can you prevent the system animation which setting the new attributes would trigger?

Comment: The appearing / disappearing attributes would be the same as the final attributes, so no animation occurs. I've only done this (manually animating a collection view) for custom selection animations, rather than insertions, so that's mostly speculation!