# UICollectionview non parallel animation

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

My question in short: how can [this effect on UICollectionView](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=30aavf7%3E&s=5) be achieved?

I have a collectionview with a custom layout that is similar to a gridlayout. Now when I enter the collectionview controller I want the cells to have a nice animation.

I know I can implement `- initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` etc and call `performBatchUpdates` on the collectionview. Now when I do this all the animations are executed in parallel (like calling UIView animate). In a lot of apps I see effects where this isn't done in paralell like the philips hue app on iPhone, the effect can be seen in the movie posted at the top. One thing I could think if is that instead of inserting all the objects here the rows are added separatly, so for instance all rows are looped and dispatched after a certain interval next from each other.

Anyway if someone could hint me what the best approach is for achieving this effect or knows about a sample that does something similar I would be very grateful.

Comment: As you have found, UICollectionView doesn't let you directly control duration for your animations. You might want to have a look at the `[CALayer setSpeed]` which lets you change the animation speed of any layer. Please be aware that this will change the animation speed for all sub layers as well, so be careful. Please read this answer for more info on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250049/uicollectionview-insertitem-adjust-animation-time

Comment: I know but this changes the speed in general, so all the items will still animate at the same speed, just a little faster or slower then apple decided for us. What I really want to know is how the effect in the movie is achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here's one way of doing it: (I felt kinda dirty after writing this.. but it works)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    myCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",indexPath.row]];

    CGRect frame = cell.myPic.frame;

    frame.origin.y = cell.myPic.frame.origin.y + 40;
    cell.myPic.frame = frame;
    cell.myPic.alpha = 0;

    [cells addObject:cell];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)Run:(UIButton *)sender
{
    for (int i=0; i<[cells count]; i++)
    {
        myCell *cell = [cells objectAtIndex:i];            

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^() {
            CGRect frame = cell.myPic.frame;
            frame.size.width = 80;
            frame.origin.y = cell.myPic.frame.origin.y - 40;
            cell.myPic.frame = frame;
            cell.myPic.alpha = 1;            

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.05]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I understand that you "don't really like" this option but I it does the trick, might be a good option to just get the visible cells from the collection view instead of adding them to an array in cellForItemAtIndexPath, but I can definitely work with this!

Comment: No problem. Using `NSRunLoop` always feels to me like going against nature but in rare cases (like this one) there's little to no harm in using it.